# IDS causing site to fail for lots of visitors

Tags: security

We are getting IDS errors left and right. We would get complaints here and there that our site isn't working and after reviewing our logs, IDS errors everywhere.

Mostly getting the error: `There is a validation error with your HTML input. Your activity is a bit suspicious, hence aborting`

We also seem to get this warning `[warning] Deprecated Path: There is a setting (generate_schema_and_data) not correctly defined. You may see unpredictability due to this. CRM_Core_Setting::setItems
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)`

Not sure if they are related - but sharing in case it is.

D7 5.24.3 (but this has existed for some time now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem can be avoided by checking 'Skip IDS check' in Drupal permissions. I have this checked for my clients, and it hasn't resulted in any problems.

The second message is 'normal' - I'm getting this message too for my clients.  I guess it's some PHP warning?

Comment: We just did that - did you check it for all user types?

Comment: Yes, for all roles.

Comment: Thanks Andy - one more question - with IDS off, do you use anything else to bolster security?

Comment: No, nothing other than some Drupal modules regarding security